# Installed SSH but no SSHD found

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_16_04_single_node_cluster.php).

In the section on installing ssh in 16.04 I did:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

I tested ssh with:

```
which ssh
```

It gave me a path indicating that it's working.

But when I tried:

```
which sshd
```

Nothing was produced. No file location no errors nothing?

How can I fix the sshd install?

---

EDIT:

In answer to steeldriver:

```
$ echo $path 
/home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/hugh/anaconda3/bin:~/anaconda/bin:~/anaconda/bin:~/anaconda/bin:/home/hugh/bin:/home/hugh/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ dpkg -L openssh-server
dpkg-query: package 'openssh-server' is not installed  
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,  
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

I should probably mention that I am running all this on a stand alone machine I don't currently have access to a server. Could that explain the problem?

Comment: Run `sudo service ssh restart` and see if you can SSH into it

Comment: Remember `which` only searches the current user's path - for a non-privileged user, that might not include `/usr/sbin`

Comment: I just tried that and I got the following error "Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found."

Comment: @steeldriver so how can I search correctly

Comment: More specifically, `ssh` is a metapackage that *should* install both `openssh-client` and `openssh-server`

Comment: How can I test if these packages are installed correctly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the outputs of `echo $PATH` and `dpkg -L openssh-server`

Comment: Installing the `ssh` package included with Ubuntu will also install `openssh-server`.  If you don't have `openssh-server` installed then you did not install the `ssh` package from Ubuntu.  Do you have foreign entries in your APT sources?  Check `apt-cache policy ssh` to see where the ssh package you installed came from.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to make this work is to install openssh-client package ( with the client tools) and the openssh-server package (with the server daemon):

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Installing the `ssh` package already does this.  The problem here is most likely that the SSH server is already running but the OP is just not seeing it with `which`.

Comment: Or maybe not, judging from other comments - see my new comment on question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response but it may be valid to some folks.

For anyone who may suffer from the same situation as the question says aka `which ssh` showing up the location but `which sshd` not showing anything, this simply means that you only have SSH client and **no SSH server** running in your machine. You can SSH to other computers but those computers cannot ssh back to you.

I tried to install ssh server through:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

When I ran `which sshd` I still could not get anything. What I did was complete removal of SSH through: *(mind you if you copy this command it wont ask you for confirmation as I have used -y confirmation)*

```
sudo apt remove ssh --purge -y
```

I then re-installed ssh (which adds **openssh-client** and **openssh-server**) through:

```
sudo apt install ssh -y
```

After re-installing ssh that way, for sanity and assurance I restarted SSH daemon through:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

when I did `which ssh`, I got a response so did when I issued `which sshd`. I hope this helps someone else. BTW The *Ubuntu 18.04* instance was on *VirtualBox* on a *Windows 10* machine, I wanted to access it from Windows (Yes, I know there is WSL and I use it).

Answer (score 0):

#### `sudo` may give you access to `sshd`:

```bash
$ sudo which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

The reasoning goes like:

- `sshd` is installed in `/usr/sbin`
- Even if your `$PATH` doesn't include `/usr/sbin`, `sudo` generally gives you access to `/usr/sbin`

By the way, this was alluded by @steeldriver's comment

> Remember which only searches the current user's path - for a non-privileged user, that might not include /usr/sbin

---

###### Comment on the edit section in your post (only in case other readers got confused by that)

I'm assuming your edit is a reply to:

> Please edit your question with the outputs of echo $PATH and dpkg -L openssh-server –
> steeldriver

But you should have run the command on the server that you installed `sshd` to, not on your client machine.

I'm not writing this because I'm asking you to fix that (I know this is an old post), but because other readers don't get confused by the output from the wrong place :)